# Passing a member function to for_each in C++03 (no boost, no c++11)

Tags: c++, stl, c++03

The "solution" below compiles but it is not what I want. I would like to pass the `put` member function to `for_each` and not `*this`. Using boost is **NOT** an option. Can this be solved within C++03?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Wheel { };

class Car {

public:

    void process(const vector<Wheel>& wheel) {

        for_each(wheel.begin(), wheel.end(), *this);
    }

    void operator()(const Wheel& w) { put(w); }

private:

    void put(const Wheel& w) { }
};

int main() {

    vector<Wheel> w(4);

    Car c;

    c.process(w);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it can, using a combination of the `mem_fun` and `bind1st` templates:

```
void process(const vector<Wheel>& wheel) {
    for_each(wheel.begin(), wheel.end(), bind1st(mem_fun(&Car::put), this));
}
```

The call to `mem_fun` creates a new function object that takes in two arguments - a `Car*` to act as the receiver and a `Wheel`, then calls `put` with the first parameter as the receiver and the second parameter as the argument.  Calling `bind1st` then locks the receiver object as first parameter of this function in place.

However, I think you will need to make one small change to this code to get it to work.  The `bind1st` adapter doesn't play well with functions that take their arguments by const reference, so you *might* need to change `put` so that it takes a `Wheel` by value rather than by reference.

Comment: Pretty sure that those are only in TR1, not C++03.

Comment: @DeadMG- Nope, those are in the <functional> spec from C++03.  The new mem_fn that's a replacement for it is far superior, though.

Comment: @Ali- The reason you can't use a reference is that, internally, the `bind1st` template tries to take its argument in as a reference to whatever the argument type is for the original function.  If the original function takes in a parameter by reference, this tries creating a reference to a reference, which is not allowed.  However, if the parameter is by pointer, that should be fine; you can have a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Awesome, works with C++03, thanks! Yes, it fails to compile with references (g++ 4.4). Could you explain why references cannot be used? How about pointers to const?

Comment: @templatetypedef: I see, many thanks for the explanation. Pointer to const was a good idea but then I have to put pointers into the container too. Well, copying the wheels is not expensive, so passing them by value is OK.

Comment: Yeah, this is the old, obnoxious way of doing it that we had to use before having something better in the form of bind().  But, doing it the hard and f'd up way is what you're stuck with when you decide to ignore the myriad of better options available to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mem_fun_ref: see [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/mem_fun_ref_t.html).

`mem_fun_ref` should work in your case where you have vector of objects:

```
for_each(wheel.begin(), wheel.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Wheel::put));
```

Note that the above example changes `put` to be a member of Wheel and not Car. It should give you an idea of how to use it though.

Use `mem_fun` if you have a vector of pointers to an object

Comment: Sorry, this does not compile. Please note that I want Car::put and not Wheel::put as in the example. (I tried to compile with Car::put.)

Comment: I think this could work, but you still need to use bind1st as in @templatetypedef's answer.

Comment: @Fred: Yeah it does work but templatetypedef's answer is better because it works without having to make put a member function of Wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Sure- you can just write your own equivalent of boost::mem_func. TR1 has one too. It's a little repetitive if you want increasing numbers of arguments, but not conceptually hard.

```
template<typename T, typename mem_func_type> struct mem_func_internal;
template<typename T, typename Ret> struct mem_func_internal<T, Ret (T::*)()> {
    typedef Ret(T::* functype)();
    T* obj;
    functype func;
    Ret operator()() {
        return obj->*func();
    }
};
template<typename T, typename Ret, typename ArgType1> struct mem_func_internal<T, Ret (T::*)(ArgType1) {
    typedef Ret(T::* functype)();
    T* obj;
    functype func;
    Ret operator()(ArgType1 arg) {
        return obj->*func(arg);
    }
 }
template<typename T, typename mem_func_type> struct mem_func : public mem_func_internal<T, mem_func_type> {
    mem_func(T* object, mem_func_type mem_func)
        : obj(object)
        , func(mem_func) {}
};
template<typename T, typename mem_func_type> mem_func<T, mem_func_type> bind_mem_func(T* object, mem_func_type func) {
    return mem_func<T, mem_func_type>(object, func);
}
// Usage
std::for_each(wheel.begin(), wheel.end(), bind_mem_func(this, &Car::put));
```

It's been a while since I wrote code like this, so it might be a little off. But that's the gist of it. So hard to write a usage example without just using a lambda.

Comment: Sorry, I am not at this level. Could you give me an example? Which one should I use and how? Thanks.

Comment: @Ali: The line given under the `//Usage` comment is an example of the usage.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last Usage line. I fixed two straightforward compile errors but after that I cannot correct the remaining ones... :(

Comment: @Ali: If you don't post it, I can't help you. @Fred: This doesn't require binding.

Comment: @DeadMG: It would take considerable time and a number of posts to fix it iteratively, exchanging a post after each fixed error. Please try to fix the code on your machine.