# How to pass pointer to a class instance's function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get a pointer to a function of an instance of my object. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

class Dice {
    int face;
public:
    Dice () {
        face = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }
    int roll() {
        face = rand() % 6 + 1;
        return face;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dice mydice;
    vector<int> v(1000);
    generate(v.begin(),v.end(),mydice.roll);
}
```

My compiler barks at me at the generate line with cryptic messages =) Please point out how to properly tell generate to call `mydice.roll()` to populate vector `v`.

Comment: `std::bind(&Dice::roll, &mydice);` - or just `[&]{ return mydice.roll(); }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ function pointer (class member) to non-static member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function)

Comment: @Xeo please use answers, instead of comments =)

Comment: @Dima he has way too much rep already

Comment: @NicolBolas I have read all of that question, but nobody there provides an answer on how to use std::bind or std::function to achieve what I need.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz One can never have enough =)

Comment: Almost the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642497/passing-a-member-function-to-for-each (I don't say "duplicate" only because you marked your question specifically for C++11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach: make use of the () operator to define your dice class itself as a functional. Include this in your class: `int operator()() { return roll(); }` , then you can simply call your generator with `generate(v.begin(),v.end(), mydice);` .

Comment: I like this answer as it is also valid C++98 which is what my course is based on.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe 2 comments from my side: 1) when using the operator(), you need to adjust the class name to keep the code self-explanatory, because you don't automatically include a verb as in the method name "roll". 2) If you want to continue using C++ after the course, do yourself a favor and look into the changes C++11 brings. They're really useful for simplifying many uglinesses of C++03 and make writing readable code much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Give it an object:

```
generate(..., std::bind(&Dice::roll, &mydice));
```

`std::bind` is in `<functional>` and binds arguments so that a function can be called without supplying them.

Comment: Coming from Python & C this syntax is totally non-obvious... Not sure how you all stand it =))) But thanks for the answer! It works \o/

Comment: @Dima, It's a functional concept, so you could say that it's non-obvious to a lot of C++ programmers as well.

Comment: Now you mention it, thinking in Lisp-like way, does make it "natural".